# How is udhcpc executed and how to change it?

Tags: networking, dhcp, udhcpc

I am working on an embedded system and it uses udhcpc as its DHCP client. It seems to be running with the following parameters:

`/usr/share/udhcpc # ps | grep dhcp
 5366 root      2432 S    udhcpc -R -b -p /var/run/udhcpc.eth0.pid -i eth0`

I want to change the parameters or run my own DHCP client. I searched and I think it has something to do with ifup and /etc/network/interfaces.

`iface eth0 inet dhcp`

But I don't see a way to modify the DHCP client.

I would like to know

1. how to change the parameter to udhcpc, and
2. if it is possible to run my own DHCP client without killing udhcpc

Thanks!

Comment: is your OS openwrt?

Comment: No. I am actually not sure what flavor of Linux it is.

Comment: can you tell me the full udhcpc path please?

Comment: /sbin/udhcpc is the full path, right?

Comment: it is just /sbin/udhcpc and it is linked to /bin/busybox

Comment: yep, I already knew it was busybox, was including that in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system seems a lightweight version/variation of Debian, based in `busybox`.

`busybox` is typically used either for recovery medium, or for embedded systems with limited resources.

For modifying the parameters, you can invoke `udhcpc` automatically.

You can change `/etc/network/interfaces` as:

```
iface eth0 inet manual
   pre-up /sbin/udhcpc -R -b -p /var/run/udhcpc.eth0.pid -i eth0
```

As for running another DHCP client, you would have to install it; however you would have to switch it with `udhcpc` unless you have other interfaces.

Bear in mind as `udhcpc` is part of `busybox`, it is just a link to a global binary that provides you with a work environment, and as such, you won't save any space switching DHCP clients.

Answer (score 2):

The solution proposed by Martin Trenkmann didn't work for me (using udhcpc_opts). However, on my system adding the following lines to `/etc/network/interfaces` worked:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
        hostname myhostname
```

This made BusyBox to execute:

```
$ ps aux| grep dhc
 1685 root     /sbin/udhcpc -n -p /run/udhcpc.eth0.pid -i eth0 -x hostname:myhostname
```

(Found at https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Udhcpc)

Answer (score 1):

> How to change the parameter to udhcpc?

You can use `udhcpc_opts` for this.

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
  udhcpc_opts -t 10
  ...
```

The example above tells **udhcpc** to try at most 10 times to get a lease.